# Is there a broader nomenclature convention to explain why the ‘a’ in ‘chlorophyll a’ is italicized?

Tags: nomenclature

By convention, the letter that specifies which side chain a chlorophyll molecule contains is italicized: for instance, chlorophyll *a*. Does this convention stem from any broader principle of chemical nomenclature, or is it more of a quirk unique to chlorophyll?

Comment: The trivial names, such as “chlorophyll _a_”, are listed in: Nomenclature of tetrapyrroles (Recommendations 1986). [_Pure Appl. Chem.,_ **1987** _59_ (6), 779–832](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac198759060779); [_Eur. J. Biochem.,_ **1988,** _178,_ 277–328](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1432-1033.1988.tb14453.x). However, no rule is given for the italicized letters.

Answer (score 2):

*This is only a partial answer to your question.*

The suffixes a and b to the name chlorophyll were most likely introduced by *Richard Willstätter* and *Arthur Stoll*. They are widely used in their book [UNTERSUCHUNGEN ÜBER CHLOROPHYLL](https://ia801409.us.archive.org/16/items/untersuchungen1913will/untersuchungen1913will.pdf) (Julius Springer, Berlin, 1913). Here, however, the suffixes are **not** yet italicized and appear as normal text.